# How to make list of dictionary from two list in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I need to make a list of dictionary from two list. keys of the dictionary is are fixed.

```
list1 = ['a','b','c']

list2 = [1,2,3]
```

i need to create a list of dictionary like this,

```
final_list = [{'name':'a','age':1},{'name':'b','age':2},{'name':'c','age':3}]
```

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
final_list = [{"name": x, "age": y} for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = ['a','b','c']
list2 = [1,2,3]

final_list = []

for i in range(len(list1)):
    final_list.append({'name': list1[i], 'age': list2[i]})
```

Comment: from where can i get list2[i] ?    do i need to add a inner loop?

Comment: no, `i` is the index of `list1` _and_ `list2` - it will go from `0` to `2` (for a list of 3 items) - this works because `len(list1) == len(list2)`

Answer (score 1):

```
final_list = [{'name':x, 'age':y} for (x,y) in zip(list1, list2)]
```

> Out: [{'name': 'a', 'age': 1}, {'name': 'b', 'age': 2}, {'name': 'c', 'age': 3}]